# Regular Expression for Username for ASP.NET

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate a username.  I would like it to follow this rule:

Contains between 5 and 20 alphanumeric characters (either lower or upper case) and up to a single period (but not at the end or the beginning).

So far I have come up with the following:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|([.])(?!\1)){5,20}$
```

This works in most cases, but it still allows usernames to have a period at the end and the beginning - could someone help me tweak it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?i)(((?=.{6,21}$)[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+)|[a-z\d]{5,20})$
```

This regex is:

- **(?i)** - case insensitive (you can also achieve this with RegexOptions);
- **((?=.{6,21}$)[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+)** - match 6-21 chars if string contain **single** period;
- **[a-z\d]{5,20}** match 5-20 chars if string not contain period.

Comment: Why is there `{6,21}` ? the question states 5 to 20 characters. It should be `{5,20}`.

Comment: Because this part matches string, that contain from 5 to 20 alphanumeric chars + exactly one period.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an simple solution :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][.a-zA-Z0-9]{3,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Just specify a character class without dot for the first and the last character.

Comment: This solution allows multiple periods.